# Finding field value pairs using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have difficulties summarizing the issue into a nice, neat title, so the title may be misleading. Here is the situation

Table 1 has an ID, an Issue, and a resolution date, so it is expected that some dates will be null. ID's can be assigned to multiple issues as well.

Table_1:

```
ID | Issue | Date
1  | a     | 1/1
2  | a     | 1/1
3  | b     | 
4  | c     | 1/2
```

I use another table to update this table, so for this example, the data in table_2 looks like:

```
ID | Issue | Date
3  | b     | 1/3
1  | b     | 1/3
```

Now, I have one query which will update table_1 dates using table_2 information, based on the ID/Issue pairing, using something like this:

```
Update Table_1 tab1
left outer join Table_2 tab2
on tab1.id = tab2.id and tab1.issue = tab2.issue
set tab1.date = tab2.date
```

However, there will be times where table 2 has ID/Issue pairs that are *not* in table_1. I would like to instead insert those rows into table_1, but I'm not sure how to do this.

If it was just one single field, say ID, i could just do something like:

```
insert into table_1 (ID, Issue, Date)
select ID, Issue, Date
from table_2 where table_2.ID not in (select ID from table_1)
```

How would I do this for an ID/Issue pairing? 
Using the above example, I would want to insert the following row from table_2 into table_1:

```
1 | b | 1/3
```

since an ID/Issue pair of 1/b exists in table 2 but not table 1.

How would I go about selecting from table 2 the id/issue pairs that do not exist in table 1?

Comment: Some databases support the concept of `MERGE` ([msft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx))([Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm))([MySQL on duplicate key update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update/548570#548570)) which will either update if key value exists, or insert. if no key value found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a left outer join to do this:

```
insert into table_1 (ID, Issue, Date)
select ID, Issue, Date
  from table_2 t2
  left outer join table_1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.ID and
                                t1.Issue = t2.Issue
 where t1.ID is null
```

This guarantees you to get every row in table_2 and then limit the rows in table two if there isn't a match in table_1.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I never thought of doing this before. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `not exists`:

```
insert into table_1 (ID, Issue, Date)
    select ID, Issue, Date
    from table_2
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table_1
                      where table_2.ID = table_1.ID and table_2.issue = table_1.issue
                     );
```